# HHELP flutter_ftms 0.6.2

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

my friends. Could you help me? I'm using "flutter_ftms: ^0.6.2" and "flutter_blue: ^0.8.0. I try to use this code, but my Visual Studio isn't recognizing the package "flutter_ftms". There's a red line under "FlutterFtms" and "FlutterFtms" in the line "FlutterFtms ftms = FlutterFtms.instance;". There's another red line under "BluetoothDevice" in the line "List devices = [];", and a red line under "BluetoothDevice" in the line "BluetoothDevice? selectedDevice;". Also, there's a red line under "BluetoothDevice" in the line "final BluetoothDevice device;", and a red line under "FlutterFtms" and "FlutterFtms" in the line "FlutterFtms ftms = FlutterFtms.instance;", as well as a red line under "StreamSubscription" in the line "late StreamSubscription subscription;". Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ftms/flutter_ftms.dart';

class BluetoothPage extends StatefulWidget {
@OverRide
_BluetoothPageState createState() => _BluetoothPageState();
}

class _BluetoothPageState extends State {
FlutterFtms ftms = FlutterFtms.instance;
List devices = [];
BluetoothDevice? selectedDevice;

@OverRide
void initState() {
super.initState();
ftms.scanForFTMSDevices().listen((device) {
setState(() {
devices.add(device);
});
});
}

@OverRide
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Bluetooth'),
),
body: ListView.builder(
itemCount: devices.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return ListTile(
title: Text(devices[index].name),
onTap: () async {
selectedDevice = devices[index];
await Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => MachinePage(selectedDevice!),
),
);
},
);
},
),
);
}
}

class MachinePage extends StatefulWidget {
final BluetoothDevice device;

MachinePage(this.device);

@OverRide
_MachinePageState createState() => _MachinePageState();
}

class _MachinePageState extends State {
FlutterFtms ftms = FlutterFtms.instance;
late StreamSubscription subscription;
String display = '';

@OverRide
void initState() {
super.initState();
subscription = ftms.connect(widget.device).listen((data) {
setState(() {
display = data.toString();
});
});
}

@OverRide
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
subscription.cancel();
ftms.disconnect();
}

@OverRide
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text(widget.device.name),
),
body: Center(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
Text(display),
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {},
child: Text('Stop'),
),
SizedBox(width: 16),
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Play'),
),
],
),
],
),
),
);
}
}'
```

I need this page using the flutter_ftms package to be able to display what appears on the machine's screen in the app. I have already tried another method and was not successful (published with another method on my profile).